# What is the appropriate preposition for a testimonial?

Tags: prepositions

Do we say:

> Can you please write up a testimonial **about** me on LinkedIn?

or

> Can you please write up a testimonial **of** me in LinkedIn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Can you write (up) a testimonial about me on LinkedIn?** is perfectly acceptable.

As a native speaker, I would personally say:

> Would you mind posting a testimonial about me on LinkedIn?

Answer (score -2):

It depends!

You **write** testimonial ***for*** someone.

> Could you please write a testimonial ***for*** me **on** my LinkedIn profile?

Someone can also **give** a testimonial. The example from [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/testimonial?showCookiePolicy=true):

> *If I told them the truth, they had no reason to believe me; Hebburn wasn't going **to give me a glowing testimonial.***

For **this particular case,** it can work *without* preposition as well:

> Could you please write a testimonial **on** my LinkedIn profile? - Since you are defining 'your' LinkedIn profile, it's undrestood that the testimonial is for you and not anyone else.

You can also have testimonial ***about*** something:

> Could you please write a ***testimonial about my work*** with your firm?

Comment: "write a testimonial FOR me" sounds to me like you don't know how to write and are asking someone more literate to write something FOR you. The OP's original ABOUT ME is more idiomatic in this situation.

Comment: that's interesting...and I agree @CocoPop

Comment: *For* doesn't sound like that to me, it sounds like how @MaulikV meant it. However, I agree that *for* is ambiguous between these two meanings and could possibly be misunderstood. *About* is the better choice for that reason.